# Search form isn't passing through the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

**Hi Guys!**

The problem is that I have a form which searches etc. The thing that go's wrong is that the first time you use the form nothing happens and it go's to domain/?. I have no idea what the problem is. I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be doing the trick. Thanks!

*It seems like it doesn't prevent the default action on the first run because I've tried and a console.log inside this function won't run.*

```
$(function () {
    $('#search-bar').on('submit', function (e) {
        var y = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();
        if (y === 'location') {
            geoSearch();
        } else {
        qCall(y);
        }
        x.val('');
        e.preventDefault;
    });
});
```

*The forms HTML has not action or method*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably cut down the form submit with e.preventDefault. According to W3C definition, the preventDefault javascript function do the following :

> **Definition and Usage** The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

For example, this can be useful when:

- Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
- Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL

So removing `e.preventDefault();` from your code should do the trick.

And by the way, you forgot the double '()' behind the function name. I'm pretty sure you made the mistake only on the code posted, but worth the warning, we never know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And sorry for wasting your time. It turns out I didn't add a () after the preventDefault so actually it wasn't ever preventing default the entire time. Your answer made me realize this.